# awk: create column with increasing values

Tags: awk

I've a text file with 3 columns like this one

```
2010-01-03 11:00:00 -134        
2010-01-03 11:01:00 -131        
2010-01-03 11:02:00 -128    
...
```

Now I need the time steps in seconds rather then the existing ones.

How can I create a new column between $2 and $3 filled with increasing values (0, 60, 120, ...) until the end of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your statement and data, you may need this:

```
awk  '{ print $1, $2, i*60, $3; i++;}' orifile
```

Answer (score 1):

in connection with the luoluo's answer, slightly shorter version: `awk  '{ print $1, $2, (NR-1)*60, $3}' orifile`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the time stamps are not all evenly spaced and that you have to parse them: With **GNU awk** you could use `mktime` to do that:

```
gawk '{ ts = $1 " " $2; gsub(/[-:]/, " ", ts); t = mktime(ts) } NR == 1 { start = t } { $2 = $2 OFS (t - start); } 1'
```

This works as follows:

```
{                           # for all lines:
  ts = $1 " " $2            # concat first and second fields,
  gsub(/[-:]/, " ", ts)     # replace - and : with spaces. The result is the
                            # format mktime expects: "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS"
  t = mktime(ts)            # convert to seconds since Epoch
}
NR == 1 {                   # in the first line:
  start = t                 # set the starting point
}
{                           # for all lines:
  $2 = $2 OFS (t - start)   # append the seconds since start to the second field,
                            # effectively inserting a third
}
1                           # then print.
```

Comment: great job, too. I'd just need it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, to insert column in `awk`

```
awk '$3=(NR-1)*60 FS $3' file
```

you get,

```
2010-01-03 11:00:00 0 -134
2010-01-03 11:01:00 60 -131
2010-01-03 11:02:00 120 -128
```